# Type of algebra needed in manifolds

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

I am an undergraduate student on my last semester before graduation. After picking classes in all three fields of pure mathematics, I have decided that in the years after I would like to focus on algebra and geometry, and more specific on manifolds.

I have taken two courses on differetintiable manifolds and this semester I am working with a professor on commutative algebra and algebraic geometry. So it was necessary for me to take a look at some tools of homological algebra, like categories and functors (Tensor and Hom).

My question is the following:

> I would like to know which fields of algebra have applications on the study of manifolds, so that I can plan my future studies regarding.

Any help would be embraced and much appreciated!

Comment: How about algebraic topology?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,to begin with !! I came across algebraic topology while I was doing some research on the subject. I actually have found some books on the topic such as Massey's and Rottman's which I would like to work with during summer.Would you recommend any other textbook??

Comment: Well, I have no better ones. But knot theory is really nice and can be considered from the algebra point of view.

Comment: I see.. I had no idea about knot theory to be honest but with a first look it seems pretty interesting. Might give it a shot, thanks !!

Comment: I think homological algebra and linear algebra are the most applied branches of algebra on manifolds. One can compute homology and cohomology of manifolds and one usually adds linear structures to the manifolds (tangent space, exterior algebra of forms, etc)

Comment: Also Lie algebras and its representation theory arises in the study of geometric structures on manifolds.

Comment: @Javi thanks for the reply! I was suspecting that linear algebra/ linear structures will have a major role to play in more advanced levels.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks for the reply mate! My uni's graduate course includes couple of lessons about Lie algebras and their reprentations which I plan to attend!

Comment: You're welcome. Depending on what you're interesed about manifolds, some basic group theory can help as well, since there are Lie groups (which are manifolds and groups at the same time) and it is very natural to consider the group of isometries of a Riemannian manifold and other groups of functions.